# plugin chart for graphael

Tags: javascript, plugins, raphael, graphael

I'm creating a plugin or at least that's what I think for gRaphael. It's a waterfall plugin and I'm trying to find where is some documentation related to best practices for creating plugins for gRaphael/Raphael. I'm looking for something like what jQuery has in its site where it explains very well what the structure should be.

Comment: Did you ever complete the plugin? I need to make a waterfall plot as well.

Comment: Havent finalized it yet, feel free to fork or download quite buggy specially with all negatives https://github.com/climboid/piesInRaphael/blob/master/example1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is rare on gRaphäel unfortunate...
Some of the beter documentation is found at  : https://github.com/kennyshen/g.raphael